# Swift with json data with list information

Tags: json, swift, ios8, xcode6

I am making and iOS app that calls history information from the database, with the use of a PHP API.

I have the output of the json displayed as following:

```
[{"ID":"6","searchTerm":"Not Responding - Windows 8.1","solutionID":"1","date":"2015-01-26 08:23:34"},
 {"ID":"7","searchTerm":"Not Responding - Windows 8.1","solutionID":"1","date":"2015-01-26 08:41:29"},
 {"ID":"9","searchTerm":"Windows 8 startup","solutionID":"6","date":"2015-01-26 08:41:29"}]
```

when the JSON was a single return array the following command worked:

```
let idusers:NSInteger = jsonData.valueForKey("idusers") as NSInteger
```

but I just cant find any solution about handling this type of data format. Any help on how I would read the JSON would be great.

For references purposes is the VC:

```
 var postData:NSData = post.dataUsingEncoding(NSASCIIStringEncoding)!

    var postLength:NSString = String( postData.length )

    var request:NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    request.HTTPBody = postData
    request.setValue(postLength, forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")
    request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")


    var reponseError: NSError?
    var response: NSURLResponse?

    var urlData: NSData? = NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse:&response, error:&reponseError)

    if ( urlData != nil ) {
        let res = response as NSHTTPURLResponse!;

        NSLog("Response code: %ld", res.statusCode);

        if (res.statusCode >= 200 && res.statusCode < 300)
        {
            var responseData:NSString  = NSString(data:urlData!, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding)!

            NSLog("Response ==> %@", responseData);

            var error: NSError?

            let jsonData:NSDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(urlData!, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers , error: &error) as NSDictionary


            let idusers:NSInteger = jsonData.valueForKey("idusers") as NSInteger
```

Comment: why not you use swiftyjson? More easy. http://blog.revivalx.com/2015/02/23/uitableview-tutorial-in-swift-using-alamofire-haneke-and-swiftyjson/

Comment: Because this is a acedemic project towards a final thesis, so to keep to quality of the meterial, plus swiftyJSON works is not a hole lot different then Swift JSON but Swift JSON is native so this in my choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get an Array of NSDictionaries from the API you would need too loop through every entry in the array and than get the value for the key.

```
if let jsonArray = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &error) as? Array<NSDictionary>
```

Comment: You are very correct! I had an array but that I was calling the information and not looping through the information I was getting errors.

Comment: if let jsonArray = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &error) as? Array<NSDictionary>